# Oracle substitution variable not working for varchar2

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I just want to use substitution variable to get the customer_name(varchar2), but when I executing the below subprogram it is raising the exception.

```
DECLARE
    v_cid     dummytest.customer_id%type := &customer_id;
    v_cname   dummytest.customer_name%type := &customer_name;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dummytest ( customer_id,customer_name ) VALUES ( v_cid,v_cname );

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Error

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 47:
PLS-00201: identifier 'HUHU' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 3, column 15:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 72:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 5, column 72:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "V_CNAME": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

But when I give values in numbers and inserting successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitution happens first, so the following...

```
v_cname   dummytest.customer_name%type := &customer_name;
```

...becomes...

```
v_cname   dummytest.customer_name%type := HUHU;
```

... which, due to the lack of single quotes is not a string, but instead, an identifier which the compiler cannot determine source.

so, if you include the quotes for a string (VARCHAR2) substitution, the following...

```
v_cname   dummytest.customer_name%type := '&customer_name';
```

...becomes...

```
v_cname   dummytest.customer_name%type := 'HUHU';
```

... which is the string you are looking for.

It works for numbers because the number type does not require the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution variables are replaced in your SQL script with the given input before the script is parsed and executed; therefore, you have to put single quotes around string substitution variables, so they become string literals eventually.

```
 v_cname   dummytest.customer_name%type := '&customer_name';
```